# Alert after page load

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

This is my script :

```
<%
    if (TempData["Resultat"] != null){
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
</script>
<%
    }
%>
```

In this case pop-up is shown before page loaded, but i want that's appear after page is fully loaded.
in Html it's looks like this :

```
<body onload="happycode() ;">
```

but i can't use it in MVC i got one master page for all my web application

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you can use jquery then you can put the alert inside the `$(document).ready()` function. it would look something like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
  });
</script>
```

To include jQuery, include the following in the `<head>` tag of your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Here's a quick example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/3AaAx/

Comment: another question in my alert special caracter are shown in ASCI code like `&#39` how to decode it ?

Comment: Is there any way I could see more code or perhaps an example and I'll try to help more.

Comment: this is my ViewData Form example `L'ajout de promotion à reussi` but in the alert the string showin is like this  showen like this `L&#39;ajout de promotion &#224; reussi`

Comment: I'm sure there's a good way to do it as it seems to be a common problem, but without having all the details it's hard to really answer. I'm also not an expert on the special character matter either. I'll keep looking into the issue though and if I find anything helpful I'll let you know. I apologize for blanking on the additional question. It may be helpful to look a bit into 'String.fromCharCode()'

Comment: Here's something similar to what you're looking for. I hope it helps! EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/3AaAx/2/  ...updated the link for more of your situation.

Comment: Hi, this alert is showen before CSS is fully loaded how can i change it to be showen after css is loaded i tried to put it in the end of page but it dosn't work

Comment: This solution is not working when you refresh the page.
It stuck in the alert without loading the page.

Answer (score 22):

There are three ways.
The first is to put the script tag on the bottom of the page:

```
<body>
<!--Body content-->
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
</script>
</body>
```

The second way is to create an onload event:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){//window.addEventListener('load',function(){...}); (for Netscape) and window.attachEvent('onload',function(){...}); (for IE and Opera) also work
    alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
}
</script>
</head>
```

It will execute a function when the window loads.
Finally, the third way is to create a `readystatechange` event and check the current document.readystate:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onreadystatechange = function(){//window.addEventListener('readystatechange',function(){...}); (for Netscape) and window.attachEvent('onreadystatechange',function(){...}); (for IE and Opera) also work
    if(document.readyState=='loaded' || document.readyState=='complete')
        alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: The first way doesn't seem to work. E.g. I have a page with a script just before `</body>` and the `alert` appears before the page appears in the browser window; in fact, the page doesn't load until after I've dismissed the `alert`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option to resolve issue described in OP which I encountered on recent bootcamp training is using window.setTimeout to wrap around the code which is bothersome. My understanding is that it delays the execution of the function for the specified time period (500ms in this case), allowing enough time for the page to load. So, for example:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                alert("Hello World!");
            }, 500); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please add a little more description to your answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, and happy debugging!

Comment: Nice thread on setTimout()  on multiple functions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839996/calling-more-than-1-function-in-settimeout

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you use it in MVC?

Rather than using the body load method use jQuery and wait for the the document onready function to complete.

Comment: The OP may not be using MVC3 for razor.

Answer (score 3):

With the use of jQuery to handle the document ready event,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoadAlert() {
    alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
}

$(document).ready(onLoadAlert);
</script>
```

Or, even simpler - put the `<script>` at the end of `body`, not in the `head`.

Comment: (reply to the deleted question): yes, I had several debug sessions, when `console.log()` and debugger gave different results

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below in the `PageLoad` Event:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "myScript", "alert('OK Done.');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
 alert('Alert after page load');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the *defer* attribute on the script, but it's only appropriate for external scripts with a *src* attribute:

```
<script src = "exampleJsFile.js" defer> </script>
```