# Calling more than 1 function in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to call two functions at the end of one `setTimeout()` in JavaScript.
Is it possible and if "yes" which one will be executed first?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    playmp3(nextpage);
    $.mobile.changePage($('#' + nextpage));
}, playTime);
```

Comment: What are playmp3 and changePage functions?

Answer (score 22):

> Is it possible?

Yes, why wouldn't it be? `setTimeout` takes a callback *function* as it's 1st argument. The fact that it's a callback function doesn't change anything; the usual rules apply.

> which one will be executed first?

Unless you're using `Promise`-based or callback-based code, Javascript runs *sequentially* so your functions would be called in the order you write them down.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  function1() // runs first
  function2() // runs second
}, 1000)
```

However, if you do this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // after 1000ms, call the `setTimeout` callback
  // In the meantime, continue executing code below
  setTimeout(function() {
    function1() //runs second after 1100ms
  },100)

  function2() //runs first, after 1000ms
},1000)
```

then the order changes since `setTimeout` is *async* in which case it get's fired *after* it's timer expires (JS continued and executed `function2()` in the meantime)

---

If you have issues with your above code then either one of your functions contains *async* code (`setInterval()`,`setTimeout()`, DOM event, WebWorker code etc), which confuses you.

- *async* here stands for *asynchronous* meaning not occurring in a particular order

Answer (score 3):

I've used this syntax and it works fine:

```
$('#element').on('keypress change', function (e) {
   setTimeout(function () { function1(); function2(); }, 500, $(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

5This worked like a charm for me (it's multiple functions that fire after an element is clicked):

```
const elem = document.getElementById("element-id");
    function parent(){
         elem.addEventListner("click", func1);
              function func1(){
                   // code here
                 setTimeout(func2, 250) //func2 fires after 200 ms
                  }
              function func2(){
                   // code here
                 setTimeout(func3, 100) //func3 fires 100 ms after func2 and 350 ms after func1
                  }
               function func3(){
                   // code here
                  }
    }
    parent():
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: it's working perfectly fine for me. With this code, you can call one function after the another using callback.

```html
<script>
  function one(callback) {
    var x = document.getElementById("d1");
    x.style.color = "red";
    x.style.background = "grey";
    console.log("one");
    
    setTimeout(two, 1000);
  }
    
  function two(callback) {  
    var x = document.getElementById("d1");
    x.style.color = "blue";
    x.style.background = "black";
    console.log("two");
    
    setTimeout(three, 1000);
  }
    
  function three(callback) { 
    var x = document.getElementById("d1");
    x.style.color = "green";
    x.style.background = "white";
    console.log("three");
        
    setTimeout(four, 1000);
  }
    
  function four(callback) { 
    var x = document.getElementById("d1");
    x.style.color = "yellow";
    x.style.background = "white";
    console.log("four");
        
    setTimeout(five, 1000);
  }
  function five(callback) { 
    var x = document.getElementById("d1");
    x.style.color = "pink";
    x.style.background = "white";
    console.log("five");

    setTimeout(one, 1000);
  }
</script>
    
<head>
  <body>
    <div id="d1">this is first division</div>
    <button onclick="one(two)">on me</button>
  </body>
</head>
```